# Parsing the data from html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the html parsed code like this , and want to get the xx@yy.com by looking for string Moderator.

```
<p>
 <strong>
 lead
 </strong>
 <span style="color: rgb(23,43,77);">
  <span>
  </span>
  :
  <ac:link>
   <ri:user ri:userkey="3333">
   </ri:user>
  </ac:link>
 </span>
</p>
<p>
 <span style="color: rgb(23,43,77);">
  <strong>
   moderator
  </strong>
  <span>
  </span>
  :
  <a href="mailto:xxx@yy.com">
   xx@yy.com
  </a>
 </span>
</p>
<p>
 <span style="color: rgb(23,43,77);">
  <strong>
   plan
  </strong>
  <span>
   <time datetime="2022-12-15">
   </time>
  </span>
 </span>
</p>
<p>
 <br/>
</p>
```

Parsing the this html string , finding many ways to get the content , getting lost .

```
poc_Integrator = soup.find('p', 'Moderator')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the desired output from this code

```
for each_p in soup.findAll("p"):
    strong = each_p.find('strong')
    if strong and strong.getText() == "moderator":
        poc_Integrator = each_p.find('a').getText()
```